# Possible Visual Studio 2015 C++ Compiler and IntelliSense Bugs

Tags: c++, intellisense, visual-studio-2015, compiler-bug

I encountered a compiler crash and intellisense false positives with Visual Studio 2015 using C++.

This crashes the compiler when written within a function block:

```
if();
```

This is the dialog that is shown when compiling (I am on a German version of Windows):

[image]

Even though the compiler crashes, I get error list output:

> Error C2059   syntax error: ')'
>   Warning   C4390   ';': empty controlled
>   statement found; is this the intent?
>   Error C1903   unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation

This produces squiggles and error annotations in the vertical scrollbar in map mode, but no actual intellisense errors:

```
#include <vector>

struct S { std::vector<S> Children; };

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    S item;

    item.Children.push_back(S());
    //           ^
    // Error: no instance of overloaded function 
    // "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=S, _Alloc=std::allocator<S>]" 
    // matches the argument list
    // argument types are: (S)
    // object type is: std::vector<S, std::allocator<S>>

    S& back = item.Children.back();
    //        ^^^^
    // Error: a reference of type "S &" (not const-qualified) cannot be
    // initialized with a value of type "S"

    return 0;
}
```

Are those bugs? Are they known? Can you reproduce them?

Comment: SO is not the place to file bug reports. I'm sure VS has its own bug tracker.

Comment: That first one's not what I'd call a crash, either. More like a controlled exit after refusing to be stupid. Sure, compiler could optimize it out and carry on, but maaaan...

Comment: @sashoalm All related "possible compiler bugs" questions have a positive rating. How do you explain that?

Comment: @BetaCarotin See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284708/what-can-we-do-with-questions-where-the-only-response-is-contact-the-vendor for reference. You're welcome to add your opinion to the discussion there about whether such questions should, or should not be asked here.

Comment: @BetaCarotin A question should cover one single topic. Yours has two unrelated ones. Also the first is not even very clear: you state *This crashes the compiler* yet all you show is a normal compiler diagnostic. That is not a crash?

Comment: @stijn They are both VS2015 problems. I don't consider those issues unrelated enough to open separate questions. Also, what do you want me to show? I assume you know what a program crash looks like.

Comment: @user4581301 I don't expect the compiler to optimize out a syntax error. It crashes, it does not terminate gracefully.

Comment: So you get something like a "cl.exe stopped working" dialog?

Comment: @stijn Yes. _Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler has stopped working_ in my case.

Comment: @BetaCarotin I stand corrected. That is definitely a crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first case: the compiler shouldn't crash but just issue the diagnostic you show. So yes, that's a bug. Which doesn't occur in VS2013 btw. Submit a report for it [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio)

For the second case: it is the same in VS2013 and is due to nesting a vector of S inside S. This and other cases make the error squiggles appear incorrectly, it is actually not that uncommon. But ideally it should not happen so you can submit a bug report for it as well, though it might be something which is going to be labelled 'wontfix' as the compiler team usually focusses on more urgent cases.